# Какие преобразования кодировки произошли со строкой?

Tags: кодировка, utf-8

Жила была utf-8 строка:
`Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей же чаю`

Строка пустилась в какие-то приключения скорее связанные с преобразованием кодировки, в результате превратилась в следующую:

```
Г‘ГєГҐГёГј ГҐГ№Вё ГЅГІГЁГµ Г¬ГїГЈГЄГЁГµ ГґГ°Г Г­Г¶ГіГ§Г±ГЄГЁГµ ГЎГіГ«Г®ГЄ, Г¤Г  ГўГ»ГЇГҐГ© Г¦ГҐ Г·Г Гѕ
```

Внимание **вопрос**: что с ней происходило?

Я разумеется попробовал определить это с помощью [Лебедевского декодера](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/) и пары аналогичных инструментов, но по-быстрому ничего вразумительного не получил.

В общем иероглифы ужасно знакомые, поэтому надеюсь что кто-то их здесь узнает)

Comment: а не дос ли это?)

Comment: @pavel, все происходит под вин-10. Но мне таке иероглифы кажутся знакомыми именно по старым досовским игрушкам)

Comment: скорее всего `windows-1251`

Comment: я понял, там происходит такое `utf-8 -> windows-1251 -> windows-1252` вот сами попробуйте https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru . Единственное некоторые символы удаляются

Comment: @Duoxx, у меня не удалось так воспроизвести) И @ Abyx привел скорее всего верную (исходя из того что мне известно о приключениях строки) схему

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Работает вот такая цепочка преобразований:

```
>>> 'Г‘ГєГҐГёГј ГҐГ№Вё ГЅГІГЁГµ Г¬ГїГЈГЄГЁГµ ГґГ°Г Г­Г¶ГіГ§Г±ГЄГЁГµ ГЎГіГ«Г®ГЄ, Г¤Г  ГўГ»ГЇГҐГ© Г¦ГҐ Г·Г Гѕ' \
        .encode('cp1251') \
        .decode('utf-8', errors='ignore') \
        .encode('cp1252') \
        .decode('cp1251')
'Съешь ещё этих мягких фр нцузских булок, д  выпей же ч ю'
```

Посмотрим что случилось с буквой `а`:

```
>>> 'а'.encode('cp1251').decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251')
'Г\xa0'
```

видимо `"Г\xa0"` при копировании превратилось в `"Г "`.

---

Как догадаться:

Есть строка "Г‘ГєГҐГёГј ГҐГ№Вё", надо преобразовать ее в байты.
Г и Ё - это кириллические буквы, значит их можно преобразовать кириллической кодировкой, 1251 или 866:

```
>>> 'Г‘ГєГҐГёГј ГҐГ№Вё'.encode('cp866')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    'Г‘ГєГҐГёГј ГҐГ№Вё'.encode('cp866')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2018' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
>>> 'Г‘ГєГҐГёГј ГҐГ№Вё'.encode('cp1251')
b'\xc3\x91\xc3\xba\xc3\xa5\xc3\xb8\xc3\xbc \xc3\xa5\xc3\xb9\xc2\xb8'
```

`"\xc3\xbc \xc3\xa5"` - это кодировка UTF-8, один байт на пробел, два байта на букву.

```
>>> b'\xc3\x91\xc3\xba\xc3\xa5\xc3\xb8\xc3\xbc \xc3\xa5\xc3\xb9\xc2\xb8'.decode('utf-8')
'Ñúåøü åù¸'
```

Опять, есть строка, надо сделать ее байтами.
Русских букв тут нет, зато есть "латинские международные", пробуем кодировку 1252:

```
>>> 'Ñúåøü åù¸'.encode('cp1252')
b'\xd1\xfa\xe5\xf8\xfc \xe5\xf9\xb8'
```

Получились байты в однобайтовой кодировке. Опять пробуем 1251 и 866:

```
>>> b'\xd1\xfa\xe5\xf8\xfc \xe5\xf9\xb8'.decode('cp866')
'╤·х°№ х∙╕'
>>> b'\xd1\xfa\xe5\xf8\xfc \xe5\xf9\xb8'.decode('cp1251')
'Съешь ещё'
```

---

Выше использовался Python3. Также подойдет любой другой язык или утилита которая умеет преобразовывать текст в байты и обратно.

Comment: О да, это оно, спасибо) А как удалось нащупать цепочку если не секрет?

Comment: Хорошо бы более явно указать, что за `encode/decode` вызовы.